# Android MotionEvent to detect only ACTION_MOVE

Tags: android, android-button, multi-touch, motion-detection, motionevent

As per android `MotionEvent` documents: A change has happened during a press gesture (between `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP`). The motion contains the most recent point, as well as any intermediate points since the last down or move event.

[ACTION_MOVE Android doc](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_MOVE)

so when i apply a `setOnTouchListene` on my view is perfectly works, It give me `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP`, and `ACTION_MOVE`

but my problem is i just want to ignore a `ACTION_DOWN` events exactly before `ACTION_MOVE`. Because `ACTION_MOVE` event occur only after the `ACTION_DOWN` event as per its documents.

my coding:

```
      button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.e("Mouse: ", "Click");
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Log.e("Mouse: ", "Move");
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

So, there is any why to ignore `ACTION_DOWN` event. Because user only want to move not want to click, and `ACTION_MOVE` is also occur `ACTION_DOWN` before it execute it self.

Thanks...

Comment: Just remove `case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:` from your code

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin, but i want to allow user to also click, and i also need of it to perform user click event. and i also want the ACTION_MOVE.

Answer (score 5):

According to your comment - you can play with counter. For example:

```
private static int counter = 0;
...  
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.e("Mouse: ", "Click");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    counter++; //check how long the button is pressed
                    if(counter>10){
                       Log.e("Mouse: ", "Move");
                    }

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(counter<10){
                       //this is just onClick, handle it(10 is example, try different numbers)
                    }else{
                       //it's a move
                    }
                    counter = 0;
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: you suggestion is good, but in your code user have to wait for response, and i want to give the response immediately.. And its not be good for my project, Thanks for response.

Comment: Best Answer for those who wants to use MOVE properly because sometimes ACTION.MOVE is called even when user touch screen simply ...So to notice proper MOVE .Counter is best solution.